# C++ QT best way to pass a message higher in class structure

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, structure

I am currently implementing a program that realizes TCP communication between PC program and external devices in QT. The problem I have is more general, but I will use this one as an example.

My class hierarchy looks like this:

```
            Program
           /       \
      Server_A <--> Server_B <--- External system
          |
       Sockets[]
       /        \
  Commands      Confirmations
                /     |     \
         Interf1   Interf2    Interf3
```

I can get a command from device (`Socket`), my command gets into `Confirmation` class, realizes any `Interface` job, and returns confirmation back to `Socket`, which sends it back to device.

The problem occurs when I want to have a command send from an external system, which I also have to confirm.

1. I get a message on `Server_B` and pass it to `Server_A` with information about: `socket` to send command to and command to realize.
2. I pass a command to a particular `socket`
3. `Socket` sends a command to `Commands`, as there is logic for an External System commands.
4. `Commands` prepares a message, runs logic, and sends(through socket) message to device
5. `Socket` waits for response
6. `Socket` gets the response, understands that it was a response to an external system command, and passes it back to `Commands`
7. `Commands` realizes its logic.

Here it would all be fine, but the next step is:

8. `Commands` need to confirm the success(or failure) to external system.

So basically, what I have to do is pass a message from `Commands` to `Server_B` this way:
`Commands->Socket->Server_A->Server_B`. For all these classes, I would have to create an unnecessary method just to pass this one information. Is there a way to somehow solve this problem? During my programming, it often occurs that I have to pass something to the higher layer of my class structure, and it looks redundant to realize it through additional methods that only passes information further.

I have provided a sample pseudocode for this problem:

```
class Program
{
    ServerB serverB;
    ServerA serverA;
}

class ServerB
{
    void send(QString msg);
}

class ServerA
{
    QVector<MySocket*> sockets;
}

class MySocket
{
    Commands commands;
    Confirmations confirmations;
}

class Commands
{
    void doLogic();
    void sendToExternalSystem(QString message); //How to realize it?
}
```

My program is much bigger, but I hope it will give you a clue what I am trying to achieve. The simplest solution would be to add a method `void sendToExternalSystem(QString message)` into Sockets, Server_A and Server_B, aswell as providing a pointer for each parent during construction (commands will have access to sockets, sockets will have access to server_a, and server_a will have access to server_b)

Comment: why does it look "terrible" ? Why do you think a method that does something useful is "unnecessary" ? Can you post a small example to illustrate the problem? Asking to avoid some code without showing the code is difficult

Comment: I have used word "redundant" instead :), I have provided simple pseudocode, hope it helps, but that's my problem - if Server_B had been a global class, it would be simple (just run Server_B.send(message)), but as it is not, I have to pass `sendToExternalSystem(QString message)` through 4 different objects, I hope I can somehow solve it while keeping good quality code, the point of my question is that I want to learn a technique to solve this kind of problem, as it occurs fairly often for me, and I believe that saving a parent pointer just because this one case might not be the best solution.

Comment: An answer of type: `it is actually the best solution to provide pointers to parent and new methods` would be fine. As for now I just have a feeling that I would do something wrong by doing it, something that could be done much better.

Comment: When something delegates some other entity to perform a task that will yield a result, you could consider the promise/future pattern

Comment: @MatG I have just checked promise/future pattern, and it looks like a good solution. Could You correct me if I am wrong, would it mean that I have to pass a promise with message, fill it with message once I want to resend confirmation, and call finish, with watcher on Server_B it will produce a signal that I will be able to handle? I am also going to use it on single-threaded application, but I believe it is not a problem with watcher's signal.

Comment: @Lidbey In the worst case you could also aggregate the data regarding the command and its status/result in a `Request` object passed to the *worker* and checked by the *requester*. If in the future you'll want to test a multi-threaded approach, you should consider a mechanism that would ease that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a solution. It was necessary to implement `ExternalCommand` class, which instances were created in `Server_B`.

In the minimal solution, it has: 1. Field `QString Message`, 2. Method `QString getMessage()`, 3. Method `void finish(QString)`, 4. Signal `void sendToExternal(QString)`

When I read the message sent from the external system in `Server_B`, I create an instance of this class, and connect it to the `Server_B` send method. In my code, it looks like that:

```
ExternalCommand::ExternalCommand(QString message, QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->message=message;
}

QString ExternalCommand::getMessage()
{
    return this->message;
}

void finish(QString outputMessage)
{
    emit sendToExternal(outputMessage);
}
```

```cpp
void Server_B::onReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = dynamic_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QString message = socket->readAll();
    ExternalCommand* cmd = new ExternalCommand(message);
    connect(cmd, &ExternalCommand::sendToExternal, socket, 
        [socket](QString message) {socket->write(message.toUtf8());});
}
```

It was also necessary to implement some type of object destruction in `ExternalCommand` once the command is sent, but it isn't the point of this question.

So once this is implemented, instead of the message as `QString`, the message is passed to the lower levels as `ExternalCommand*`, and once an answer is got, it is possible to send it back to the External System, by calling `ExternalCommand::finish(QString outputMessage);`. Of course, this is just a minimal solution for this problem.

Thanks to @MatG for pointing me to Promise/Future pattern, which was helpful in finding this solution.